# Google BigQuery SQL: working with an array?

Tags: arrays, count, google-bigquery

I'm a newbie at SQL and Google BigQuery. 
I'm trying to run the following query to get a list of names and counts, however I see that I am getting an array error and don't know how to fix it. Any help appreciated.

ERROR MESSAGE:

Cannot access field harmonized on a value with type ARRAY at [5:27]

```
#standardSQL
-- Applications_Per_Assignee
SELECT assignee_harmonized.name AS Assignee_Name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Patent_Apps
FROM (
SELECT ANY_VALUE(assignee.harmonized.name) AS Assignee_Name
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS patentsdb
GROUP BY Number_of_Patent_Apps
)
GROUP BY assignee_harmonized.name
ORDER BY Number_of_Patent_Apps DESC;
```

Comment: Hello @Marko43, and welcome to SO. You should at least post the entire error message along questions like these. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60776921/edit) your question to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ah.name AS Assignee_Name, 
  COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Patent_Apps
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) ah
GROUP BY Assignee_Name
HAVING Number_of_Patent_Apps < 1000
ORDER BY Number_of_Patent_Apps DESC
-- LIMIT 10
```

with output

```
Row Assignee_Name                   Number_of_Patent_Apps    
1   SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO LTD      600678   
2   CANON KK                        579731   
3   MATSUSHITA ELECTRIC IND CO LTD  560644   
4   HITACHI LTD                     531286   
5   SIEMENS AG                      486276   
6   MITSUBISHI ELECTRIC CORP        461673   
7   IBM                             438822   
8   SONY CORP                       438039   
9   FUJITSU LTD                     384270   
10  NEC CORP                        357193
```

Comment: Mikhail, one additional question. If I want to use logical operators to filter the count, I see that inserting something like WHERE COUNT(*) < 1000 wont work and produces an 'aggregate' error. What is the trick to doing this with an array such as this?

Comment: `HAVING Number_of_Patent_Apps < 1000` - see update in answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few things wrong with your query.

- `assignee` is a string, I think you want to look at `assignee_harmonized.name`
- You will want to `UNNEST()` `assignee_harmonized`
- `ANY_VALUE()` only selects a random value, which does not sound like what you want
- You have a `GROUP BY` in your inner select, which will not give you the results you want
- You don't really need a subquery for this type of query.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ah.name AS Assignee_Name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Patent_Apps
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS patentsdb
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) ah
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```